# AWS kinesis agent on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We are trying to use [AWS Kinesis Agent to write data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html)

How can we [install it and configure the config file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html#config-start) when we are using Elastic Beanstalk? (we don't want to ssh into the instance of course)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there's a way to add your kinesis configuration inside the elastic beanstalk service inside this [folder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html)

and create a file like `kinesis-agent.json` with the following configuration, but you can use yaml file as well

```js
{
  "cloudwatch.emitMetrics": true,
  "cloudwatch.endpoint": "",
  "firehose.endpoint": "",
  "kinesis.endpoint": "",
  "flows": [
    {
      "filePattern": "${file.path}",
      "kinesisStream": ""
    },
  ],
  "log.level": ""
}
```

also, you can check [this example](https://support.treasuredata.com/hc/en-us/articles/207048577-Installing-td-agent-on-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk) on how to use `.ebextensions` dictionary.